# Storing government forms

Tags: sql

I want to store a large number of filled-out government forms, like the [Application for Federal Assistance](http://www2.ed.gov/fund/grant/apply/appforms/sf424CoreForm.pdf). The forms are varied and change yearly. Field types vary, and can be: boolean, string, date, int, among others.

Is the best way to store these forms to completely normalize data?

À la:

```
form
+-----------------+-----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field           | Type      | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------------+-----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id              | int(11)   | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| govt_identifier | char(40)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| description     | char(100) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------------+-----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

filled_form (a form a person has actually filled out)
+-----------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field     | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id        | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| form_id   | int(11) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| person_id | int(11) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

text_field (a class of input; belongs to a form)
+---------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field   | Type     | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id      | int(11)  | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name    | char(40) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| form_id | int(11)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+---------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

text_value (a particular input record; belongs to a class and filled_form)
+----------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field          | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id             | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| value          | text    | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| text_field_id  | int(11) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| filled_form_id | int(11) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+----------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

... continue for all input types
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While this would work, your SQL will be slightly awkward and quite non-intuitive.  Have you considered actually creating data models for each form individually and then using those to populate your forms.  It may seem more work up front, but the development of your data capture will potentially be simpler.

Comment: I prefer this, but what if I want to query all models who answered "yes" on question 18? I'd have to load all models, without a database's convenience of filtering by an attribute.

Comment: @Jasie - I'm not sure I understand.  Is question 18 going to be common across different forms?  Surely if your model is a table called FederalAssistance and question 18 (hopefully more reasonably named) is a bit filed, it's just a matter of select * from FederalAssistance where Question18 = 1?

Comment: I see, so you still advocate storing them in SQL databases, but in a more specific way. I thought you meant, store the Form models as an object on the filesystem (with a reference in the database).

Answer (score 0):

I would have a look at [single table inheritance](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/singleTableInheritance.html).
Model each field as a base class `Field` with subclasses `IntField`, `BoolField`, etc.

The `Field` class will have a member `Name (string)`, `IntField` will have `IntValue (int)`, `BoolField` will have `BoolValue (bit)`, etc.

This requires you to have one column for each possible type in your `Field`-table, that is a bit space overhead, but on the other hand it gives you type safety. If you model as single table inheritance you can probably hook up your favorite ER-mapper without problem.